# Unicode character (hexagon) not displayed on some computers

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, device

I have a huge problem. I just updated my websites homepage to display a unicode hexagon character: ⬢ `&#x2B22;` aka U+2B22
I made it 200px big and filled it with text. It looks good and works fine on my computer. With both Internet Explorer (win8) and Firefox 28.
I tested it on 5 different computers and it didn't work there! Tested with Firefox 28 and Internet Explorer (win7) on each device and on one computer even with the newest Chrome.

So what am I doing wrong? How is it possible that it works on my FF 28 and on 5 different devices with FF 28 it doesn't?

I already tried:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

and in HTML directly:

```
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Is U+2B22 not part of utf-8?

Try it yourself here, scroll to the very bottom of: http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html
For my PC it looks like this: http://250kb.de/u/140401/j/RzN1lYTL8fLJ.jpg
On other devices it looks like this: http://250kb.de/u/140401/p/VEeerGhyv4lM.png

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character U+2B22 BLACK HEXAGON is included in a few fonts only. None of those font comes with Windows or with other widely used software, so in most computers, there is no font containing it. Moreover, browsers may fail to render the character even if some font in the system has it. For some more general explanations, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

In this case, the font setting is `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica`. None of those fonts contains the character, so each browser tries to use other fonts in the system, in a browser-dependent order. In your own computer, you have a font that contains the character. You may have downloaded and installed it, or it may have come along with some software

What you could do is, alternatively,

a) specify, in a `font-family` declaration, a list of fonts known to contain the character. This could help against problems of browsers not finding a font, but this would not matter much.

b) use a downloadable font (web font, via `@font-face`). This would mostly be overkill if you just want one character for essentially non-text use. Fonts that contain U+2B22 are generally large.

c) use an image instead, possibly as a background image. This would be here the rational choice, especially since you would not use U+2B22 as a character in text but as a background of a kind.

Regarding the question “Is U+2B22 not part of utf-8?”, characters aren’t really part of utf-8. Instead, utf-8 is a transfer encoding for characters, and all Unicode characters (and, moreover, all Unicode code points) have representations in utf−8. Besides, the page mentioned does not contain U+2B22 as such but as the character reference `&#x2b22;`, and this works independently of character encodings. Thus, this is not an encoding problem, but a font issue.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will go will go with the background-image.

Comment: What's more, the exact size and shape of the hexagon would depend on the font design, so you wouldn't be able to rely on that for layout (text ‘inside’ it would often end up mispositioned). An image (bitmap or maybe SVG) makes more sense.

Comment: @bobince, yes, though for a character like U+2B22 we can expect the *shape* to be the same (a geometric form)—but the size, relative to font size, may vary, and does vary.

Answer (score 2):

These computers on which it does not work do not have a font installed which contains a glyph for this particular character. That is all.

Solutions would include to not depend on users having fonts with such unusual characters installed and provide them as web font instead (which you might have to create) or to use an image, SVG or canvas instead.

Comment: Weird, I think I already tried it with Arial, which is very common. However, which font would you suggest me to use?

Comment: On my OS X machine only 4 fonts I happen to have installed contain that symbol: Free Monospaced, STIXGeneral-Regular, Symbola, Apple Symbols. I don't think any of those come with Windows by default. I don't think there's a generally compatible solution, or at least you'd have to research it yourself.

Comment: Well, I don't need one font that works on every computer. If the user uses mac I will just go with Free Monospaced and now I need a font that my site uses when the user uses windows.

Comment: And I don't know what the answer is there. BTW, Apple Symbols is probably the safer bet for OS X. And, be aware that it'll look slightly different in each font.

Comment: I don't think that this is related to the installed fonts. I tried: Arial, Times New Roman, Calibri and Segoe UI Symbol. It worked on my computer every time and on the other devices it didn't.

Comment: Open Windows' charmap utility and check out those fonts, see if they actually contain the character. Browsers typically will fall back to any other font that's installed on the computer if the specified fonts don't contain the character. They'll look for the character no matter what. If you get the "no character font" icon instead, it means *no* installed font has it.