# Hexagon CSS Width & Height %

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway of creating an Hexagon with the property's set to % instead of px's?
So i could create a div container within my website with a width and height of 100px's, the hexagon set to 100% width and height would take up the entire div?
Thank you for any reply! :)

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px; 
  height: 40.41px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 20.21px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 20.21px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 20.21px solid #64C7CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

*edit*
In case someone wants it made a kind of really sloppy solution where you can change the pixels of the container to change the hexagon

```css
.container {
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
}
.hexagon1 {
 position: relative;
 height: 30%;
 width: 30%;
 top: 15%;
 left: 10%;
 background: #76B4FF;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.hexagon2 {
 position: relative;
 height: 30%;
 width: 30%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 16%;
 background: #76B4FF;
}
.hexagon3 {
 position: relative;
 height: 30%;
 width: 30%;
 top: -15%;
 left: 10%;
 background: #76B4FF;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.hexagon4 {
 position: relative;
 height: 30%;
 width: 30%;
 top: -60%;
 left: 4%;
 background: #76B4FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="hexagon1">
</div>
<div class="hexagon2">
</div>
<div class="hexagon3">
</div>
<div class="hexagon4">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not possible when using your current approach because here the hexagon is done using `border` and that property cannot take percentage values. Your options would be using `transform` like in [**this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/98ec13h5/) or `clip-path` (low browser support) or SVG. If you are ok to use the transform method (or one of the others), I can give a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `em` units since `border` can't do percents. This way you only have to specify the hexagon size in one place, with `font-size`:

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.hexagon {
    font-size: 400px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0.86602540378em;
    height: 0.5em;
    background-color: #64C7CC;
    margin: 0.25em 0.0669872981em;
}
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 0.43301270189em solid transparent;
    border-right: 0.43301270189em solid transparent;
}
.hexagon:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0.25em solid #64C7CC;
}
.hexagon:after {
    top: 100%;
    border-top: 0.25em solid #64C7CC;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
</div>
```

It is not the most ideal solution however, since it's not relative to the container size.

Comment: This is amazing thank you!
I found another way using 4 different div's all % shaped in a container like a hexagon, but your way seems really clean and neat and appreciate your response :)

Comment: dam, this one doesn't work that well with border colors and transparent fill.:(

Answer (score 2):

A lot of possible solutions come to mind, here are two of them:

## Overlapping Rectangles and percentages

As we all know, hexagons are made of 6 equilateral triangles. However, you can also simulate a hexagon using 3 overlapping rectangles, that are rotated by 60 degrees around their center point but otherwise identical.

Those rectangles have to have the right proportions, but they are easily computed:

Let `d` be the diameter of the hexagon, `a` the long side of the rectangles, and `b` the short side, then we get:

`a = sqrt(3)/2 * d` (roughly 0.866)
`b = 0.5 * d`

Using that knowledge and [a really nice trick to make the width of a div relative to its height](http://Maintain%20the%20aspect%20ratio%20of%20a%20div%20with%20CSS), it is possible to craft a solution, where you only need to change **one single value**, the width of the parent div, to change the size of your hexagon.

Here's the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 270px; /* This is the only value you need to change */
}

.container {
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 86.6%; /* This sets the height of the div to 86% of its width */
  border: 1px dashed green; /* Just for demonstration purposes*/
}

.hexagon {
  position: absolute; /* so .hexagon isn't pushed out of .container by the padding */
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* center .hexagon inside .container*/
  background-color: red; /* color of the hexagon */
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  display: block;
  position:absolute; /* otherwise :after is below the hexagon */
  top:0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.hexagon:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hexagon">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Some minor drawbacks**

This solution has some really small drawbacks:

1. I'm adding extra markup, `.wrapper` and `.container`. Unfortunately the latter is unavoidable. `.wrapper` can be avoided, if you set width and height of `.container` manually, but isn't it cool that you only have to change one value instead of two?
2. If you want to use a translucent background-color using `rgba()`, what you'll actually get is a dark small hexagon inside a lighter star inside an even lighter hexagon. You can circumvent that by giving `.container` an `opacity`

Side note: Contrary to what one commenter said, I wouldn't worry about browser support for `transform`: Even unprefixed it's far from being poor and if you're using prefixes, there's nothing to worry about unless you have to support IE8.

### The Unicode way

One of the more creative solutions (and the solution I posted originally) is to use the unicode hexagon and adjust the font-size.

However this solution has some rather severe problems:

1. You need a font that supports this. Apparently out of the box Windows has no font that actually supports this. So you need to use a Webfont. However Google fonts has no font with that glyph, neither does Font Awesome or Glyphicons. So you're left with hosting a font yourself.
2. It's a lot more difficult to get the size an position right, this will include a lot of trial and error and I assume that even if you get it right the solution will be shaky and cost a lot of headache if you need it to be responsive as well.

So maybe this solution will be usable in the future, but for now it has only some academic value, however here's the code:

```css
.hexagon:before {
  content:'\2b22';
  color:#64c7cc;
  line-height:1;
}

.hex-sm {
  font-size:40px;
  height:40px;
  }
.hex-md {
  font-size:100px;
  height:100px;
  }
.hex-lg {
  font-size:200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hexagon hex-sm">
</div>
<div class="hexagon hex-md">
</div>
<div class="hexagon hex-lg">
</div>
```

Here's some information about the [unicode character 'BLACK HEXAGON' (U+2B22)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b22/index.htm) and if you're looking for a font that supports it, [Code2000](http://www.fontspace.com/james-kass/code2000) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my part. I get the ordinay rectangles, no hexagons.

Comment: You're right, I forgot something: You need a font that supports that character. It works like a charm on my computer. Unfortunately, as far as I could find out, there are no cross-OS standard fonts that support it. I'll try to figure out a font-cascade that does the trick and if I can find anything that works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22796466/192077 So it seems an external font is the only way to do it like this.

Comment: Yep, I looked through Google fonts to find a font that supports this, but I didn't find one. No luck with Glyphicons or Font Awesome either, so the only solution left is self-hosting a font like Code2000. Maybe my solution will work better in the future, once browsers and OS's (I'm looking at you, Windows) have caught up.